# Confused by doubleclickevent and mousepressevent in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

The situation is:

In side a `QGraphicsView`, I used its `doubleClickEvent` function to create a `QGraphicsItem`.
I rewrite the `QGraphicsItem`'s `mousePressEvent` function to simply print a `qDebug` information.

However, what I found is that: even if I just double click to create that `QGraphicsItem`, the newly created `QGraphicsItem`'s `mousePressEvent` is also called.

How would this happen? What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A QGraphicsView is a widget, so it has a doubleClickEvent. In contrast, a QGraphicsItem is not a widget, but has a mousePressEvent.

When you override events, if you don't want them to be propagated to other objects, you need to [accept](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qevent.html#accept) the event to tell the system that you've handled it.

```
void MyGraphicsView::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
   // Create a graphics item..
   ...
   event->accept(); // tell the system that the event has been handled
}
```

Without accepting the event, the double click is passed on to the QGraphicsScene and then QGraphicsItem.

If you want to be able to double-click to create an item when clicking on an empty area of a scene, but have an item react if you double-click on an item, you can override the scene's [mouseDoubleClickEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent) instead of the view and check if there's an item at the cursor position before deciding upon whether or not to create an item, or pass the event on.

```
void QGraphicsScene::mouseDoubleClickEvent( QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent )
{
    if(items(mouseEvent->scenePos()).isEmpty()) // if no items are at this position
    {
         // create new graphics item
         ...
         mouseEvent->accept(); // don't propagate the event
    }

    // no items, so allow the event to propagate by doing nothing
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems that I have a misunderstanding with mousepressevent though.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: In the Windows case, what's the condition to trigger a mousepressevent? I am looking for doc from qt, but hard to find...

Comment: Ultimately, it's a reaction to a mouse down event from Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx